# How exactly does "shear stress" and "viscosity" work when it comes to a fluid?

Tags: hydrology, sedimentology, visualization

From [Crash Course Engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouTJkNLepF0), understanding the movement of fluids requires knowing:

1. Shear Stress
2. Shear Strain
3. Viscosity

Now, I understand that *Shear Stress* causes *Shear Strain*, and depending on the *Viscosity* of the fluid, this makes the fluid move in some way. However, in my Sedimentology class, they never talk about shear strain, and only about shear stress. The example they use is from Boggs:
[image]

This makes no sense whatsoever, as it is treating shear strain like shear stress, and yet they are completely different concepts. It gets more confusing, as the equations they are using are for shear strain, and not shear stress. Furthermore, every single diagram for shear "stress" in a liquid involves the one above, but what is even happening here? If I take a block of wood, place it on a tub of water, and push it across the water, I do not see how the motion depicted above is even possible. This also contradicts the example my professor shown in class:
[image]

Why is the velocity gradient larger for the molasses? Since it is more viscous, should not the gradient be extremely small?

I am a visual learner, and not only are they using "shear stress" wrong to my knowledge, but the visual makes no practical sense; I can not find any demonstration online either. Can anyone better explain how "shear stress" and viscosity work? Why is "shear stress" used incorrectly, and why is a visual of shear strain used for the visual of "shear stress"?